# Ведет ли phpmyadmin логи о перезагрузках сервера баз данных?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Иногда база данных становится недоступной на некоторое время, могу я узнать, не из-за перезагрузки ли это сервера БД на хостинге? В поле работы сервера большое значение, месяцами не выключался. Может это дисконнекты между файлопомойкой хостинга и базой данных? Посоветуйте как проверить.

Comment: Самое простое - логи смотрели?

Comment: Приложение на одном хосте ну никак не может вести логи о сервисе на другом хосте. Но у MySQL есть свои собственные логи, где много что можно почитать...

Comment: В phpmyadmin глядел пункт "состояния". Нашел выделенные красным пункты в списке, но там ничего критичного.

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';` покажет, сколько секунд уже работает процесс MySQL после старта.